# What is the best menu metaphor for silverlight line-of-business apps?

Tags: silverlight, menu, line-of-business-app

So I'm porting an application from **WPF** to **Silverlight** and I have realized that there is no standard **Menu** control.

So I look around and find some **third-party** controls that **emulate** the menu control, like [this one at codeplex](http://slmenu.codeplex.com/):

[alt text http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/1adt6b3.png](http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/1adt6b3.png)

But then I decided to **take advantage of this situation** and think of some **new metaphors** besides the standard menu we have been using since **Windows 3.0**, e.g. I like the following **enabled/disabled buttons** for a small number of choices, which also work well as a vertical stack, and will try to integrate a **[drop-down button](http://www.tanguay.info/web/index.php?pg=codeExamples&id=140)** idea to allow it to hold the number of nested choices that a standard menu control could hold:

[alt text http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/1bbtg9l.png](http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/1bbtg9l.png)

**What is the best application navigation menu metaphor you have seen or used in a Silverlight line-of-business application?**

Answer (score 3):

How about the Office Ribbon?

http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/01/20/ribbon-control-for-silverlight.aspx
http://www.divelements.co.uk/net/controls/sandribbonsl/
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa973809.aspx

Comment: +1 for leading me to this live demo of a silverlight ribbon, impressive: http://divelements.co.uk/net/controls/sandribbonsl/livedemofullscreen.htm

Comment: I agree and the price is not that bad for the lone developer. (no affiliation with product)

Comment: +1 for ribbon as well, though there are free versions as well. http://silverlightribbon.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I like the style of Apple's CoverFlow.

You can load various screens in each of the CoverFlow "panels", show the Active panel in the center, and tightly pack the other panels to the left and right.

You gain the ability to allow the user to see their other panels while working on the active one...and you can add a little flair when the user switches between the panels.